# PHP Script Cron Job Blocked My VPS Server?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, .htaccess, shell

I have a script on my server that runs according to a cron job that's set to run every minute. This script has two steps.

**Step 1: Import**

Script imports data to temp table - everything is okay.

**Step 2: Populate (Breaks here)**

Script is suppose to populate the data from the temp table to live sql table.

**Conclusion:**

I checked the PHP code in the script and my cron job is set to run every minute. Everything is okay and confirmed by 2 developers.

**The ISSUE:**

It seems that the server is terminating the script untimely and it's blocking it to run again.

I removed the code below from my root .htaccess file, but that didn't help.

```
# secure htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# multiple file types
<FilesMatch ".(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

I am running a VPS CENTOS 5.9 i686 virtuozzo – host WHM 11.38.0

Comment: the obvious problem to me would be the script that "populate the data from the temp table to live sql table." your server issue assumption seems weird

Comment: Are you trying to run the script by accessing it via url (wget or similar) instead of running via CLI?

Comment: if the script is running via cron job, .htaccess have NO effect to it. Could it possible be that your script is firing one after another without waiting the first one to end **(even if its set to run every minute, if the first run takes longer than 1 minute it should trigger it again)** producing too many process resulting on it being killed before finishing or locking itself ? Also do you have CSF/LSD installed?